# FETCH for uploading folder with multiple files DOES NOT ABORT when I close the Tab

Tags: node.js, input, file-upload, fetch-api, svelte

I'm trying to implement a multiple file loader in my web app, i.e. I want to upload to a given path in my local machine a folder with multiple files in it.
I'm using Svelte for the frontend part and Express for the backend part.

So far I've done the following. Client side:

```
  async function load_report() {
let first_input = document.getElementById("folder");

let files_list = Array.from(first_input.files);
let local_files_paths = files_list.map((f) => f.webkitRelativePath);
const payload = new FormData();

for (let i = 0; i < files_list.length; i++) {
  payload.append("files", files_list[i]);
  payload.append("local_files_paths", local_files_paths[i]);
}

try {
  isUploading = true; // to disable the buttons for other uploading operations
  const response = await fetch("/upload_report", {
    //signal: signal,
    method: "POST", // or "PUT"
    body: payload,
    // No content-type! With FormData obect, Fetch API sets this automatically.
    // Doing so manually can lead to an error
  });
  isUploading = false;
  let fetch_msg = await response.json();
  if (!response.ok) {
    upload_report_error = `${fetch_msg["title"]}: ${fetch_msg["message"]}`;
    alert.addAlertToStore(
      "danger",
      fetch_msg["title"],
      fetch_msg["message"]
    );

    console.error(fetch_msg["message"]);
  } else {
    alert.addAlertToStore(
      "success",
      fetch_msg["title"],
      fetch_msg["message"]
    );
  }
} catch (e) {
  console.error(e);
} finally {
  //$alert = `Todo '${name}' has been added`;
  first_input.value = null;
}
}
```

and also in my onMount() function:

```
  onMount(() => {

    window.onbeforeunload = function () {
      if (isUploading) {
        return "You are uploading! CHILL OUT!";
      }
    };
```

Server-side, the endpoint is treated in this way:

```
app.post("/upload_report", async(req, res) => {
  if (!req.files) {
    return res.status(400).send({ title: 'upload_folder_error', message: 'No files were uploaded.'});
  }
  let date;
  try{
  date = req.body.local_files_paths[0].match(/([0-9_-]+)\//)[1];
  }catch(e){
    return res.status(500).send({ title: 'upload_folder_error', message: e.message });

  }
  if(fs.existsSync(`./app/${date}/folder`)){
    return res.status(500).send({ title: 'upload_folder_error', message: 'this folder already exists' });
  }

  for(let i= 0; i< req.body.local_files_paths.length; i++){
    let _file = req.files.files[i];
    //move photo to uploads directory
    _file.mv(`*some_path*`);
  }
  console.log('DONE');
  return res.status(200).send({ title: 'upload_folder_success', message: 'Folder correctly uploaded' });
});
```

My problem is that when I try to close the tab, a pop up alert appears telling me If I really want to close the tab, and I can either confirm or cancel the operation. But, when I confirm the operation, I would expect the fetch to be consequentially aborted (correct me if I'm wrong) but instead it goes on server side (i.e. I can see my server logging "DONE") and the files are correctly uploaded... what I'm missing in that?

PS. I also tried to use the AbortController() and calling abort inside the onbeforeunload event, but that seemed to me to be wrong.
Could you please help me to figure it out? Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like the files already made their way to the server as if you closed the client the connection should drop and the upload should fail. Try uploading a very large file to see if it still occurs.

Comment: The same occurs with large files, we're talking about 2/3+ GB content..

Comment: Try this: accept the dialog then actually quit your browser and see what happens.